# Invalid layout param in a RelativeLayout: layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I am getting the below error for my android layout file in Eclipse editor :

```
Invalid layout param in a RelativeLayout: layout_weight
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_input"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What's wrong with my layout_weight ?

Comment: You can use `weight` property in LinearLayout.

Comment: android:layout_weight is not applicable for relativeLayout.It is valid in LinearLayout or TableLayout.Replace your RelativeLayout with LinearLayout

Comment: layout_weight property is only for LinearLayout.

Comment: `layout_weight` used for Parent `LinearLayout` but here your parent layout is `RelativeLayout`. So you can't use it.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. If anyone can post the comment as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Relative layout does not support** `weight`.

`Linearlayout` support it. You can use `Linearlayout` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="Horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="0.3" for the second EditText.

Answer (score 0):

layout_weight used for Parent LinearLayout but here your parent layout is RelativeLayout. So you can't use it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="Horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```